# In Quickblox, how can we rotate a video (90 degrees, for example) in Android app (QBRTCSurfaceView)?

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, quickblox

We are streaming a video chat using Quickblox and we'd like to be able to rotate it (90, 180, 270 degrees).

In the iOS SDK this seems possible, but with Android there doesn't seem to be a setting. How can we get around this and display the video rotated? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a View method : void setRotation (float rotation) like below :

```
your_vide_view.setRotation(90f);
or
your_vide_view.setRotation(180f);
or
your_vide_view.setRotation(270f);
```

this method work for sdk >15

you should also add this condition :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            your_vide_view.setRotation(180f);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late, but for anyone wondering how to rotate the video view, you can get the video track and call addSink() function to retrieve each frame. You can then rotate the frames and call onFrame() function on the videoview. Please find the sample code below.

Remove any renderers before adding the below code and also do not add any renderers because the below code will do that.

```
 localVideoTrack?.track?.addSink { videoFrame->
            localVideoView.onFrame(VideoFrame(videoFrame.buffer, 90, -1))
        }
```